# Having a DIV be open or closed on page load (based on a checkbox status)

Tags: forms, html, post

I currently have a form.. (.php page)

that upon button click/submission runs a little .js function to do some minor form validation checking..etc.. (checks if fields are filled out..etc)

and then posts a 'REVIEW' state (posts to itself) of what was entered/submitted..

if correct, you click the submit button..

if -not- correct, you click an EDIT button.. (and go back to original -sticky- form, where you have your original data entered, for editing)..

in my main/normal form.. I have a 2 check boxes, that if checked.. reveals a DIV underneath it...  un-check checkbox, and the div is NOT displayed..

my problem or question is.. when a user wants to EDIT the details that were entered..(clicking the edit button).. and goes back to the MAIN form..

How can I either show or hide that DIV based on if a checkbox was checked?

currently.. the checkbox 'state' is being saved..and reposted to the page.. the checkbox itself is remembering/displaying the current/correct state...

but I need to be able to check this checkbox state (on page load?) to either show or hide that DIV when in EDIT mode..

I hope that makes sense.

Seems like I just need a little function to check the checkboxes value..and if either one if checked, show the div...

Maybe a little jQuery?  php $_POST[] check?..then somehow call a jQuery function from php?

to summarize:

I have a page that has a checkbox 'set' from using a PHP  $_POST[] variable...
I need to check if this check box IS set.. and if so.. show a div below..

here is my current attempt:

(Im placing this at the bottom of the page before

however I cant NOT get it to work.. if I strip out everythign but the alert.. the alert fires.. but if I keep alert in there.. and the subsequent lines after.. nothign fires/work (not even the alert)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("function check");
    alert(document.getElementById('#inhonor').checked);
    if(document.getElementById('#inhonor').checked){
        alert("function fired");
        document.getElementById('#hm_Form').style.display = checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    });                 
});
```

if I JUST put this in the function: alert("function check");

it fires..

if I add anything else to it.. (the function never fires. no alerts.. no DIV showing..etc)

suggestions?

Any advice is appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there was a syntax error..  an extra ')' hidden in there. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(document.getElementById('#inhonor').checked){
        alert("function fired");
        document.getElementById('#hm_Form').style.display = checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    };                 
});
```